# Getting the Frequency of Elements in a Table With Respect to Another Column

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby, frequency

I have a question about converting a table into another format based on the frequency of a column and grouped by another column. I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I'm having trouble finding the correct keywords for searching, so I figured I'd ask the question.

I have the following table:

| Patient | Diagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| Ralph | A |
| Ralph | A |
| Steve | B |

And I'd like to convert it to this:

| Patient | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ralph | 2 | 0 |
| Steve | 0 | 1 |

Any help or pointers would be appreciated! I've gotten as far as `df.groupby("Patient").Diagnosis.value_counts()`, however this doesn't include all diagnoses for patients (i.e. patients that have 0 counts for a diagnosis).

Comment: You can try `pd.crosstab(df['Patient'], df['Diagnosis'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shubham commented, you can [cross tabulate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Patient': ['Ralph', 'Ralph', 'Steve'],
    'Diagnosis': ['A', 'A', 'B'],
})
pd.crosstab(df.Patient, df.Diagnosis)
```

Output:

```
Diagnosis   A   B
Patient         
Ralph       2   0
Steve       0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

- simply it's the `len()` of each of the **Patient** and **Diagnosis**
- `unstack()` to make **Diagnosis** columns
- rest is details to arrive at your specific output

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Patient Diagnosis
Ralph   A
Ralph   A
Steve   B"""), sep="\t")

df = (df.groupby(["Patient","Diagnosis"]).agg(len)
 .to_frame().unstack().droplevel(0, axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)
 .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

|  | Patient | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Ralph | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | Steve | 0 | 1 |